# How to read data from file and display in QEditText box in QT

Tags: c++, python, linux, ubuntu, qt4

i would like to read a line of  data from text file and display that data in Text Edit box

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple, actually:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


FILENAME = 'textedit_example.py'


class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.edit = QTextEdit()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.edit.setText("No file found")

        with open(FILENAME) as f:
            self.edit.setText(f.readline())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Some notes:

1. Save it as 'textedit_example.py' and run. You'll see the first line of the source in the text box (`import sys`)
2. It requires Python 2.6 and latest PyQt4 to run

Answer (score 0):

You may interest to look at this tutorial

[Simple Text Viewer Example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/help-simpletextviewer.html)